# Does using Mathematica to do integrals in problems from Griffith's EM hamper my physics education?

Tags: soft-question, education, software

I am a sophomore taking an Electromagnetic Theory class using Griffiths. When working on the problems in the text I sometimes encounter integrals that are quite involved at least compared to what I am used to doing. Our professor recommended that we use Mathematica to do them for us. My only worry with this approach is that I might miss out on practice doing calculations by hand which may be important a physicists education (I am not sure if this is the case). Do you think it is worth working out these problems by hand and would I be losing insight by using Mathematica?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you understand the process you would need to solve the integral, you're not gaining much by actually doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several benefits in using mathematical packages to perform calculation. (I use Maple.) Perhaps it can help one with some mathematical proficiency to perform these calculations by hand if they are not too complicated. However when these calculation become very complicated it wastes time unnecessarily to try and do them by hand. With such complicated computations there is a larger change to may copy errors when doing it by hand.

The calculation itself is not the physics. It is just math. The physics come by understanding what the math represents. That can be done regardless whether you do the math by hand or with the aid of a program.